# Show 90% percentile in Bar Charts Power BI

Tags: powerbi

My Data is like this

```
User_ID  Stage_1  Stage_2  Stage_3  StagesTotal
---------------------------------------------------
U000     3        9        8        20
U111     5        7        2        14
U222     3        6        5        14
U333     6        5        8        19
U444     8        4        6        18
U555     2        7        7        16
U666     5        5        4        14

------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a bar chart that shows the median

[image]

That is good

instead of the median i want to show the 90% percentile

I tried creating a new measures

```
Stage1_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[Stage1],90)
Stage2_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[Stage2],90)
Stage3_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[Stage3],90)
StagesTotal_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[StagesTotal],90)
```

When I add the new meseare to my chart it breaks

[image]

it becomes like this

[image]

bu the chart turns to this

[image]

my question is how to display the 90% percentile in that report data

Note : the 90% measure will be used in many other charts once it is fixed

Comment: Thanks that works, plz put it in an answer so i mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have entered what I believe to be a simple mistake where you wrote `(Stages[Stage],90)` :

```
Stage_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[Stage],90)
```

It should be this instead :

```
Stage_90Perc = PERCENTILE.EXC(Stages[Stage], .90)
```